# With PodSecurityPolicy enabled, do I need to give all 44 system service accounts the "use" verb for the "privileged" policy?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have created what seems like a standard set of [RBAC](https://gist.github.com/medined/73cfb72c240a413eaf499392fe4026cf) policies and enabled the `PodSecurityPolicy` admission controller. I know how to create Roles and RoleBindings to allow my own service accounts (for example, a `deployer` account) to `use` the `privileged` policy to allow them to create pods and other actions.

**Edit** - I counted clusterroles instead of service accounts in my initial post. I have fixed this below.

There are 44 system service accounts in my cluster according to `kubectl get serviceaccount -A | grep system | wc -l`. **Are the rules for each account already delineated?** I could update each rule for them to `use` the `privileged` policy but that seems too heavy-handed.

**Update** - When the PSP admission controller is enabled, `kubectl` uses the `privileged` pod security policy. However, every other service account
uses the `restricted` pop security policy. Each service account that needs elevated permissions needs to be updated in some way. But which service account needs which permission is not clear to me.

**What I want to achieve:** For each service account in the `kube-system` namespace, what permissions are needed so that I can follow the *Principle of Least Privilege*.

I am using Kubernetes v1.18.5 installed using KubeSpray. This cluster is running on AWS.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, as `kubectl get clusterroles` gives you [clusterrole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example). You can list `service account` using `kubectl get serviceaccount -A`. What is your env, its On-Prem, local? What K8s version are you using. What you want to achieve exactly?